# The font size doesn't work

Tags: css, font-size

i have this page:

http://www.tirengarfio.com/rs2/web/miembros/prueba

as you can see the font size is 16px but i have defined a 12px font in the file main.css.

I'm using Firefox 3.6.

Any idea?

Javi

Comment: The `main.css` is 404.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double check the path to your style sheets.  I can't access it.

Comment: In case you want the real answer, it's farther down.

Answer (score 3):

Like others have said, instead of

```
/css/whatever.css
```

try

```
css/whatever.css
```

Doing this from my browser brought up your stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/main.css"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/formularios.css"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/portada.css"> -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/rs2/web/css/main.css"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/rs2/web/css/formularios.css"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/rs2/web/css/portada.css">
```

It seems like you are duplicating by mistake each stylesheet. Try deleting the first three lines which return 404.

Saludos ;-)

Answer (score -2):

The problem is that your markup is not [valid](http://validator.w3.org/) — specifically, you do not have a doctype declaration (`<!doctype html>`) at the beginning of your source.

Comment: Also lack of head and body tags

Comment: ^ That is a reply to rossisdead, not the answer (which was given by myself, and is correct).